# OpenGL 3.3 C++ drawing a line for orbit path for a solar system

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently working on an assignment on creating a solar system using openGL. I've managed to create the planets, orbit of planet around the sun, and rotation of each planet axis.

i'm stuck on how do i dynamically draw a line for the orbit path for the planets. so that even if the orbit path changes the line would change.(those thin lines that shows the orbit path in most solar system images)

Hope to get a direction to work towards to instead of the answer.

Thanks ahead for the replies (if any)

P.S : Using GLFW not GLUT library. Below is what i have so far

```
static void init(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Create the shader object
    g_shaderProgramID = loadShaders("ModelSpaceVS.vert", "ColorFS.frag");

    // Getting Locations of shader's variables
    GLuint positionIndex = glGetAttribLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "aPosition");
    GLuint colorIndex = glGetAttribLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "aColor");
    g_modelMatrixIndex = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uModelMatrix");

    // Creating camera object
    // Set camera's view matrix
    g_camera.setViewMatrix(vec3(0.0f, 15.0f, 0.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), vec3(0, 1, 0));

    // Window Aspect Ratio
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    float aspectRatio = static_cast<float>(width) / height;

    // Set camera's projection matrix
    g_camera.setProjectionMatrix(perspective(45.0f, aspectRatio, 0.1f, 100.0f));


    // Initialise the model matrix to identity matrix
    //    Set to 1.0f so that during the transformation process where
    //    the matrix is multiplied, it would be 1*<value> = <value>
    //    The transformation && scale && rotate are placed in the update_scene Function
    //    as the update scene needs to update the orbitting value as well
    g_modelMatrix[0] = mat4(1.0f);
    g_modelMatrix[1] = mat4(1.0f);
    g_modelMatrix[2] = mat4(1.0f);
    g_modelMatrix[3] = mat4(1.0f);
    g_modelMatrix[4] = mat4(1.0f);

    // Generate identifier for VBO and copy data to GPU
    glGenBuffers(4, g_VBO);

    // Binding the vertices for the planet (Only 1 vertices for sun + 4 planets)
    // Transformation is not done here
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(planetOrigin), planetOrigin, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_indices), g_indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Line Vertex
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[2]);  // Binding the VBO
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(linePos), linePos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);   // Copy data to buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[3]);  // Binding the VBO
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(lineColor), lineColor, GL_STATIC_DRAW);  // Copy data to buffer

    // generate identifiers for VAOs
    glGenVertexArrays(2, g_VAO);

    // create VAO and specify VBO data
    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[1]);
    // interleaved attributes
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionIndex, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertices), reinterpret_cast<void*>(offsetof(Vertices, position)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorIndex, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertices), reinterpret_cast<void*>(offsetof(Vertices, color)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionIndex); // enable vertex attributes
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorIndex);

    // Binding the VBO to a VAO
    // Lines
    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[1]);  // Create the VAO object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[2]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[3]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

}

//   Keyboard Input Actions
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
// Exit the program on ESC
if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
{
   // Closes the window and end the program
   glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
   return;
}
else if (key == GLFW_KEY_P && action == GLFW_PRESS)
{
   // Animating the planets Orbit around the sun
   // and also their own individual rotation about their own axis
   if (animate == false)
      animate = true;
   else if (animate == true)
      animate = false;
}
else if (key == GLFW_KEY_R && action == GLFW_PRESS)
{
   // Randomize the Size / Orbit Speed Around  the Sun / Rotation Speed about their own axis
   // of all the planet and the sun
   //
   //
   // Rand + 100 to prevent the orbit or rotationSpeed from being 0
   //    Or being too low that it seems to stop
   // 
   // Randomizing the orbitSpeed of planet
   // Capping the orbit Speed at 300, minimum 100
   orbitSpeed = (rand() % 200) + 100;

   // Randomizing the rotationSpeed of planet + sun
   //    upon its own axis
   // Capping the rotation Speed at 300, minimum 100
   rotationSpeed = (rand() % 200) + 100;

   // Randomizing the planet/sun size
   // Values of the rand() is to ensure the planet will never be bigger than the sun
   // rand() % 3 / 10 + 0.7 = min : 0.7, Max : 1.0
   // rand() % 5 / 10 + 0.2 = min : 0.2, Max : 0.7
   sunSize = (rand() % 2) + 3.0;
   planetSize1 = (rand() % 2) + 0.9;
   planetSize2 = (rand() % 2) + 0.9;
   planetSize3 = (rand() % 2) + 0.9;
   planetSize4 = (rand() % 2) + 0.9;
}
else if (key == GLFW_KEY_1 && action == GLFW_PRESS)
{
   // Set the camera view to a far-away top down view of the 
   // solar system
   // Looks like a RTS camera style
   // Set camera's view matrix
   g_camera.setViewMatrix(vec3(0.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), vec3(0, 1, 0));
}
else if (key == GLFW_KEY_2 && action == GLFW_PRESS)
{
   // Set the camera view to a top down view
   // directly looking at it from above
   // Set camera's view matrix
   g_camera.setViewMatrix(vec3(0.0f, 20.0f, 0.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), vec3(0, 1.0, 0));
}

}

static void cursor_position_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    // variables to store mouse cursor coordinates
    static double previous_xpos = xpos;
    static double previous_ypos = ypos;
    double delta_x = xpos - previous_xpos;
    double delta_y = ypos - previous_ypos;

    // pass mouse movement to camera class
    g_camera.updateYaw(delta_x);
    g_camera.updatePitch(delta_y);

    // update previous mouse coordinates
    previous_xpos = xpos;
    previous_ypos = ypos;
    }

     //   Frame Buffer Action
    static void framebuffer_Size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
    {
    string title = "Assignment 1 - " + to_string(width) + " x " + to_string(height);

    glfwSetWindowTitle(window, title.c_str());
} 

 // error callback function
static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
// output error description
cerr << "Error Occurred: " << description << endl;                                                                                                  
}

//   Update Scene Function
//      Updates the "planet" solitary rotation about its own axis
//      Updates the "planet" orbit around a point around the "sun"
static void update_scene(GLFWwindow* window, double frameTime)
{
    static float rotateAngleY = 0.0f;
    static float rotateAngleY1 = 0.0f;
    static float rotateAngleY2 = 0.0f;
    static float rotateAngleY3 = 0.0f;
    static float sunRotateAngleY = 0.0f;
    static float orbitAngle1 = 0.0f;
    static float orbitAngle2 = 0.0f;
    static float orbitAngle3 = 0.0f;
    static float orbitAngle4 = 0.0f;

    if (animate == true)
    {
       rotateAngleY += 1.5 * rotationSpeed * frameTime;
       rotateAngleY1 += 1.0 * rotationSpeed * frameTime;
       rotateAngleY2 -= 2.0 * rotationSpeed * frameTime;
       rotateAngleY3 -= 2.5 * rotationSpeed * frameTime;
       sunRotateAngleY += 0.1 * rotationSpeed * frameTime;

       orbitAngle1 += 0.6 * orbitSpeed * frameTime;
       orbitAngle2 += 0.5 * orbitSpeed * frameTime;
       orbitAngle3 += 0.2 * orbitSpeed * frameTime;
       orbitAngle4 += 0.1 * orbitSpeed * frameTime;
    }

    // Updating the Scene the rotate the individual planets
    // Each of the planet needs their initial translate/scale value
    //    if the transform/scale here is vec(0.0,0.0,0.0) || vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0)
    //    They will be rendered on the origin, which is where the sun is
    //    at the same size
    //
    // rotate(radians(orbitAngle1), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f))  - Controls Orbit Rotation of Planet
    // rotate(radians(rotateAngleY), vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)) - Controls Orbit About Own Axis
    // rotate(radians(-60.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f))       - Controls the rotation of a planet on display(without movement)
    g_modelMatrix[0] = translate(vec3(0.0f, 0.0, 0.0f)) * rotate(radians(sunRotateAngleY), vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0f))
                      * scale(vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) * sunSize);

    g_modelMatrix[1] = rotate(radians(orbitAngle1), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)) * translate(vec3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) + (sunSize/10)) * rotate(radians(rotateAngleY), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f))
                   * rotate(radians(-60.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)) * scale(vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) * planetSize1);

    g_modelMatrix[2] = rotate(radians(orbitAngle2), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)) * translate(vec3(4.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) + (sunSize/10)) * rotate(radians(rotateAngleY1), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f))
                   * rotate(radians(-45.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)) * scale(vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)* planetSize2);

    g_modelMatrix[3] = rotate(radians(orbitAngle3), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)) * translate(vec3(6.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) + (sunSize/10)) * rotate(radians(rotateAngleY2), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f))
                   * rotate(radians(45.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)) * scale(vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) * planetSize3);

    g_modelMatrix[4] = rotate(radians(orbitAngle4), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)) * translate(vec3(8.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) + (sunSize/10)) * rotate(radians(rotateAngleY), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f))
                   * rotate(radians(60.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)) * scale(vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) * planetSize4);

}

//   Render Scene Function
static void render_scene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);   // Clear colour buffer && clear depth buffer
    glUseProgram(g_shaderProgramID);

    // Make VAO active
    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[0]);     
    // Sun Object
    // compute multiplication of model, view and projection matrices
    mat4 MVP = g_camera.getProjectionMatrix() * g_camera.getViewMatrix() * g_modelMatrix[0];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_modelMatrixIndex, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    // Planet 1
    MVP = g_camera.getProjectionMatrix() * g_camera.getViewMatrix() * g_modelMatrix[1];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_modelMatrixIndex, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    // Planet 2
    MVP = g_camera.getProjectionMatrix() * g_camera.getViewMatrix() * g_modelMatrix[2];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_modelMatrixIndex, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    // Planet 3
    MVP = g_camera.getProjectionMatrix() * g_camera.getViewMatrix() * g_modelMatrix[3];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_modelMatrixIndex, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    // Planet 4
    MVP = g_camera.getProjectionMatrix() * g_camera.getViewMatrix() * g_modelMatrix[4];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_modelMatrixIndex, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glFlush();  // Flushing the pipelines
}
//   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//   Main Function
int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    GLFWwindow* window = NULL; // Creating of window variable

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    // Initialise glfw
    //    if false = failed initialization
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
       cout << "glfw Initialisation failed" << endl;
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Declaring the version of OpenGL
    //    Version 3.3 in this case
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    // Creating the window object
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1080, 720, "Assignment 2 - 1080 x 720", NULL, NULL);

    // Check if the Creating of window Object succeeded
    if (window == NULL)
    {
       cout << "Creation of window failed" << endl;
       glfwTerminate();
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Making Context Current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Determine Swap Buffer Interval
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // Set a background color for window
    //    Black - Solar System in space
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    // Initialise GLEW
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
       cout << "Initialisation of GLEW failed" << endl;
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Keyboard/Mouse Input/Callbacks
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_Size_callback);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, cursor_position_callback);

    // Init function
    init(window);

    // Frame Variables
    double lastUpdateTime = glfwGetTime(); // last update time
    double elapsedTime = lastUpdateTime;   // time elapsed since last update
    double frameTime = 0.0f;            // frame time
    int frameCount = 0;                 // number of frames since last update

    // Rendering Loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
       g_camera.update(window);
       update_scene(window, frameTime);
       render_scene();

       // Swap Buffer
       glfwSwapBuffers(window);
       // Poll Events
       glfwPollEvents();

       frameCount++;
       elapsedTime = glfwGetTime() - lastUpdateTime;   // current time - last update time

       if (elapsedTime >= 1.0f)   // if time since last update >= to 1 second
       {
          frameTime = 1.0f / frameCount;   // calculate frame time

          string str = "FPS = " + to_string(frameCount) + "; FT = " + to_string(frameTime);

          glfwSetWindowTitle(window, str.c_str());  // update window title

          frameCount = 0;               // reset frame count
          lastUpdateTime += elapsedTime;   // update last update time
       }

    }

    // Cleaning Up Shader Program
    glDeleteProgram(g_shaderProgramID);
    // Cleaning Up Vertexes
    glDeleteBuffers(14, g_VBO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(2, g_VAO);

    // Destroying the window before terminating the program
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: drawing a line is just like drawing a polygon, but instead if GL_TRIANGLES you use `glDraw[Elements|Arrays](GL_LINES, ...)`

Comment: @dynamitos ah i see, so i use a function to create the vertices that plots the path, and just draw it manually? is there other method besides this, just curious about it. Thank you so much for the reply & help anyway (:

Comment: @cinimod I mean there IS the possibility of using `glBegin(GL_LINES)` but that is ugly, low performance, bad practice and not OpenGL 3.3 as you have asked. GL_LINES works just like GL_TRIANGLES with the difference that it only takes 2 vertices per call, not three, and the width can be set with `glLineWidth(float)`

Comment: @Dynamitos ah yes, i understand now. Appreciate the effort spent on the replies its been really helpful!

Comment: Could you write an answer? This looks like this question should have an answer